# Generic stack in plain C does not copies structures correct

Tags: c, generics, stack, memcpy, structure

So I have implemented a generic stack in Plain C. It should copy different type of data, inclusive structures. And by structures I have the problem.

So here's the structure of the stack:

```
/*
 * Definite genStack as a structure.
 * Pointer elems points to the objects lying on the stack
 * The variable elemSize spiecifies the size of an element
 * The variable logLength specifies the number of actually
 * lying on the stack objects
 * The variable allocLenght specifies the allocated size
 */

typedef struct{
void* elems; 
int elemSize; 
int logLength; 
int allocLength;
}genStack;
```

Push and pop functions:

```
void GenStackPush(genStack *s, const void *elemAddr)
{
    /* if stack is full - allocates more memory */
    if (GenStackFull(s))
    {
        GenStackAlloc(s, s->elemSize);
    }
    memcpy((char*) (s->elems)+(s->logLength), elemAddr, sizeof(*elemAddr));
    s->logLength++;
}

void GenStackPop(genStack *s, void *elemAddr)
{
      if(GenStackEmpty(s))
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't pop element from stack: stack is empty.\n");
      } else
      {
        s->logLength--;
        memcpy((void*) elemAddr, (s->elems)+(s->logLength), sizeof(s->elems[s->logLength]));
      }
}
```

Simple structures test:

gentest.h:

```
#ifndef GENTEST1_H
#define GENTEST1_H

typedef struct {
  char* name;
  int age;
  char gender;
}person;

#endif
```

gentest.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "gentest1.h"
#include "genstacklib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  genStack StructStack;
  person testPerson[5];
  person* newPerson;
    person* test;
  int i;

  newPerson = (void*) malloc (sizeof(person));

  testPerson[0].name = "Alex";
  testPerson[0].age = 21;
  testPerson[0].gender = 'm';

  testPerson[1].name = "Vanja";
  testPerson[1].age = 20;
  testPerson[1].gender = 'm';

  testPerson[2].name = "sjrgsde";
  testPerson[2].age = 11;
  testPerson[2].gender = 'w';

  testPerson[3].name = "wergsggsd";
  testPerson[3].age = 99;
  testPerson[3].gender = 'y';

  testPerson[4].name = "adaasxx";
  testPerson[4].age = 13;
  testPerson[4].gender = 'g'; 


  GenStackNew(&StructStack, sizeof(person));
    printf("sizeof(person) = %lu\n", sizeof(person));

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    newPerson = &testPerson[i];
      GenStackPush(&StructStack, newPerson);
    printf("Pushed: %s, %d, %c\n", newPerson->name, newPerson->age, newPerson->gender);
  } 

test = (void*) malloc (sizeof(person));
test->name = "test";
test->age = 0;
test->gender = 't';
  while(!GenStackEmpty(&StructStack))
  { 
      GenStackPop(&StructStack, test);
      printf("Popped: %s, %d, %c\n", test->name, test->age, test->gender);
  }

  GenStackDispose(&StructStack);
  return 0;
}
```

And here's the output I get:

```
./gentest1
elemSize = 16   GenStackInitialAlocationSize = 4
sizeof(person) = 16
Pushed: Alex, 21, m
Pushed: Vanja, 20, m
Pushed: sjrgsde, 11, w
Pushed: wergsggsd, 99, y
    New size of alloc = 8
Pushed: adaasxx, 13, g
Popped: adaasxx, 0, t
Popped: wergsggsd, 0, t
Popped: sjrgsde, 0, t
Popped: Vanja, 0, t
Popped: Alex, 0, t
```

As you can see, I can receive names, but no age or gender. I've tried a lot of options, but still getting Segmentation Fault or the output from above. For moment, the output above is the finest output I get, but still not what I want.

The question is - how can I get the output I need?
Thanks in advance.

To avoid some questions:
sizeof(person) = s->elemSize

It is defined by creating the stack:

genstacklib.c:

```
void GenStackNew(genStack *s, int elemSize)
{
    void* newElems;

    /* Allocate a new array to hold the contents. */
    newElems = (void*) malloc(elemSize * GenStackInitialAlocationSize);
    printf("elemSize = %d\tGenStackInitialAlocationSize = %d\n",
              elemSize, GenStackInitialAlocationSize);
    if (newElems == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error with allocating the stack.\n");
        exit(1); /* Exit, returning error code. */
    }
    s->elems = newElems;
    s->elemSize = elemSize;
    s->allocLength = GenStackInitialAlocationSize;
    s->logLength = 0; /*is empty*/

}
```

gentest.c:

```
GenStackNew(&StructStack, sizeof(person));
printf("sizeof(person) = %lu\n", sizeof(person));
```

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through this in a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above the push is copying the wrong size of data.  It should be `elemSize`.
The `memcpy` is also overwriting its own data.  Something like this should work.

`memcpy((char*) (s->elems)+(s->logLength)*elemSize, elemAddr, elemSize);
s->logLength++;`

Answer (score 1):

your push function is copying `sizeof(*elemAddr)` and that is a `void *`, so it has the size of a pointer not the inteded size of a `person` struct. So you are probably copying only the first 4 bytes

Comment: When i'm trying to copy s->elemSize bytes (by person it's 16 bytes), I receive Segmentation Fault

Comment: do a `sizeof(person)` you will be amazed by the results, because it is probably 12. A pointer is just a variable with an address. Do some more research on a subject called deep copy (as opposed to shallow copy)

Comment: @hexa: If this is a 64-bit platform, then it's almost certainly not 12.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `elemSize` in all the relevant places...

Comment: I use elemSize to allocate memory. 
If I'm trying to copy s->elemSize bytes (by person it's 16 bytes), I receive Segmentation Fault

Comment: @Bfcm: Then you have more than one bug.  You should use the debugger to find out what it is.

Comment: @Bfcm: Wherever you need to operate on things that are of size `elemSize` (copying, adjusting pointers, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
void GenStackPush(genStack *s, const void *elemAddr) 
{
  ...     
  memcpy((char*) (s->elems)+(s->logLength), elemAddr, sizeof(*elemAddr));
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is *very* wrong; the type of the expression `*elemAddr` is `void`, which is a constraint violation (`sizeof` may not be called on an expression of incomplete type, and `void` is an incomplete type).  You will want to turn up the warning level on your compiler.  I wrote a test program to compute `sizeof` on expressions of type `void *` and `void`, and I get a warning with `gcc -pedantic`.  If I drop the `-pedantic` I don't get a warning, but the result I get for `sizeof (void)` is 1, which I'm pretty certain is *not* the size of a `person`.  Why aren't you using `s->elemSize` here?

Secondly, why are you casting `s->elems` to `char *`?

**EDIT**

If I may offer some advice, I've womped up a few generic containers in the past, and here are the lessons I've come away with:

First, delegate *all* type-aware operations (allocation, deallocation, copy, compare, display, etc.) to separate functions, which are called via function pointers passed as parameters to the generic container's functions; i.e., a push would be defined like

```
GenStackPush(genStack *stack, const void *data, void *(*copy)(const void *))
{
  stack->elems[++stack->logLength] = copy(data);
}
...
void *myIntCopyFunc(const void *data)
{
  const int *inputData = (const int *) data;
  int *copy = malloc(sizeof *copy);
  if (copy)
    *copy = *inputData;
  return copy;
}
...
GenStackPush(&myIntStack, &intVal, myIntCopyFunc);
```

One issue you have with your `person` type is that you're not doing a deep copy of the `name` member; you're just copying a pointer value to the stack. In this case it's not a big deal since you're working with string literals, but if you were using, say, a local `char []`, you'd have problems.  By writing a separate copy function for each type, you can deal with those sorts of issues, instead of trying to do a one-size-fits-all allocation in the container function itself.

Secondly, don't call your generic container functions directly; put a type-aware interface between you and the container (basically, the poor man's version of function overloading):

```
void pushInt(GenStack *stack, int intVal)
{
  GenStackPush(stack, &intVal, myIntCopyFunc);
}
...
genStack myIntStack;
...
pushInt(&myIntStack, 5);
```

This gives you two benefits; first, it allows you to pass literal values as parameters (which you can't do with parameters of type `void *`).  Secondly, it gives you a way to enforce type safety on your container.  You can't accidentally push a value of the wrong type this way.

Is this a lot of extra work?  Oh my yes.  There's a *lot* of magic that has to happen under the hood for generic container types to work properly.  If you're trying to replicate the same kind of functionality that you get with the C++ `std::stack` container type, you're going to be writing a *lot* of code.